# nHibernate map a property from many-to-many with filter (It Is like One-To-One)?

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many, one-to-one

I've a Many-To-Many relation but I need to restrict it to only one row that have a specific data in a column.

This is the relation:
[image]

I need to Map in the "Product_Type" entity the "Label" field as if it were in the entity.

How can I filter the "Product_Type_Culture" data where CultureCode=System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name.Substring(0, 2).ToUpper() to heve only one row in it and map the label in the "Product_Type" entity ??

I already made the filter, in session ecc...

This is my "rude" wrong mapping.

```
public class Product_TypeMap : ClassMapping<Product_Type>
    {
        public Product_TypeMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Column("Id"));

            Bag(x => x.Label, c =>
            {
                Table("Product_Type_Culture");

                c.Key(k =>
                {
                    k.Column("ProductTypeId");
                });

                c.Filter("cultureFilter", f => f.Condition("CultureCode = :cultureId"));
            }, r => r.ManyToMany(m =>
            {
                m.Class(typeof(Product_Type_Culture));
                m.Column("CultureCode");
            }));

        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: why do you want to hide the fact that the label is localized? Isn't a convenienceproperty to get the actual label enough?

Comment: I think that deceiving the application that is not localized reduce it's complexity. Imagine you want to represent a grid with all records of Product_Type with the current localization of label. If I've the localized label as a field of the entity I just add @Model.Label to the view. Instead I need something like @Model.Langs[CurrentCulture].Label. And what about querys?

Comment: 1. you can still have a property Label and use `@Model.Label` in the view 2. When inserting localisations you need access to all localisations 3. hiding it also creates complexity (eg through filters) which leak here and there. I just want to mention some issues you have to deal with

Comment: I've to use localization in 2 mode: 1) Use Localized label for presentation and search. 2) Use Localized N:M Entity for edit localized labels. For (2) there is no problem because i Use a one-tomany mapping to manage the localization. (1) Instead is a problem because when I create the views it is more simple to use @Model.Label. I do not know how to Map the Label to get it from localized table for only the record in current language.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIk it is not possible to set filter on Property() or Join()

### Option 1

i would get rid of the language table and have the Texts table as Element table for a map

```
public class ProductType
{
    public virtual IDictionary<string, string> Labels { get; private set; }

    // used for Binding etc
    public virtual string Name
    {
        get
        {
            string label;
            var currentlanguage = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;     // eg en-US
            if (!map.TryGetValue(currentlanguage.Name, out label) &&        // en-US
                !map.TryGetValue(currentlanguage.Parent.Name, out label))   // en
            {
                label = "fallback name";
            }
            return label;
        }
        set { Names[Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name] = value; }
    }
}
```

and use the following FNH Mapping (translate to MbC)

```
public ProductTypeMap()
{
    [...]
    HasMany(pt => pt.Labels)
        .Table("Texts")
        .KeyColumn("ProductTypeId")
        .AsMap("CultureCode")
        .Element("Label")
        .Not.LazyLoad()
}
```

Advantage: flexible
Disadvantage: possibly some more data fetched than needed, can not query on label

### Option 2

move the culture name in the Labels-table and use a Formula which is initialised in the mapping

```
public ProductTypeMapping()
{
    Property(pt => pt.Label, o => o.Formula("CultureCode = " + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name));
}
```

Advantage: only fetch the relevant data
Disadvantage: can not change culture at runtime, can not update label

### Option 3

combine one with a filter to reduce data fetched

```
public ProductTypeMap()
{
    HasMany(pt => pt.Labels)
        .Table("Texts")
        .KeyColumn("ProductTypeId")
        .AsMap("CultureCode")
        .Element("Label")
        .ApplyFilter("cultureFilter", "CultureCode = :cultureName or CultureCode = :parentCultureName")
        .Not.LazyLoad();
}
```